# Starting a service via a SwitchPreference

Tags: android, service, preferencescreen

can anyone tell me how can I start/stop a location service (or any other service) when a SwitchPreference in a PreferenceScreen is toggled on/of?
I'm using a settingsFragemnt (extending PreferenceFragemntCompat), which is hosted in my settings activity.

Comment: Could you please add your fragment code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add OnPreferenceChangeListener which will allow you to listen switch changes:

```
   final SwitchPreference onOffRandomColor = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(this.getResources()
                                                    .getString(R.string.sp_key_on_off_random_color));

        onOffRandomColor.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                if(onOffRandomColor.isChecked()){

                }else {

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Next step is to run service:

`startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));`

Comment: yeah I know, my point is how can I start the service inside the listener? because what i did seems not to work

Comment: Is Location service your custom service ?

You can start custom service via startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
In your case 
@Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Settings.setBoolean(Settings.DO_NOT_LOCATE, true);
                startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
                return false;
            }

Answer (score 0):

my fragment looks like this:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey){
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey);

    // setting summaries for both list preferences ---------------------------------------------
    ListPreference photo_quality = findPreference("photo_quality");
    if (photo_quality != null){
        photo_quality.setSummaryProvider(ListPreference.SimpleSummaryProvider.getInstance());
    }

    ListPreference uploads = findPreference("upload_options");
    if (uploads != null) {
        uploads.setSummaryProvider(ListPreference.SimpleSummaryProvider.getInstance());
    }

    // setting the visibility for location service ---------------------------------------------
    if (!Auth.getCanDeactiveGps()){
        Objects.requireNonNull(getPreferenceScreen()
                .findPreference("location_category")).setVisible(false);
    }

    // handling locationSwitchPreference change ------------------------------------------------
    SwitchPreference locationSwitch = findPreference("location");

    if (locationSwitch != null){
        locationSwitch.setChecked(Settings.getBoolean(Settings.DO_NOT_LOCATE,
                false));

        locationSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Settings.setBoolean(Settings.DO_NOT_LOCATE, true);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```